# How to destroy parts in order by colour

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox, luau

While scripting a game in ROBLOX I was unable to make a script that removed a part in order by colour.

I tried:

```
local partColours = {'Really Red', 'Really Blue', 'Magenta', 'Lime Green'}
local folder = game.Workspace.Color:GetChildren()
for i, v in pairs(folder) do
    if v.BrickColor == partColours then
        wait(1)
        v:Destroy()

    else
        error('L')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do those would be to loop through the folder of parts multiple times. Each time looking for the next color in the list.

Also, to make sure you are making the right comparison, be sure to check the [BrickColor's Name](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/BrickColor#Name).

```lua
local partColours = { 'Really red', 'Really blue', 'Magenta', 'Lime green'}
local folder = game.Workspace.Color

-- look for each colour at a time
for _, colour in ipairs(partColours) do
    local parts = folder:GetChildren()
    for _, part in ipairs(parts) do
        -- escape if the object doesn't have a BrickColor property
        if not part:IsA("BasePart") then
            continue
        end

        if part.BrickColor.Name == colour then
            part:Destroy()
            wait(1)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The code only destroys the magenta part

Comment: @monke, the color names from the original code sample were not capitalized properly. I've updated the code to use the correct names.